# how to unittest a vuejs component update with methods using promise

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, jestjs, axios

I'm testing a Vue component with Jest. This is my working directory :
[image]

Here is my component `Subscription.vue` :

```
<template>
  <div id="page">
    <page-title icon="fa-list-alt">
      <translate slot="title">Subscription</translate>
      <translate slot="comment">Consult the detail of your subscription</translate>
    </page-title>

    <panel v-if="error">
      <span slot="title">
        <icon icon="fa-exclamation-triangle"></icon>
        <translate>Error</translate>
      </span>
      {{ error }}
    </panel>
    <panel v-else-if="subscription_dict">
      <span slot="title">{{ _subscription_address }}</span>
      <div class="row" v-if="subscription_dict.product.hsi">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
          <subscription-hsi-panel
            :hsi="subscription_dict.product.hsi"
            :business="context.business">
          </subscription-hsi-panel>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row" v-if="subscription_dict.product.itv">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
          <subscription-itv-panel
            :itv="subscription_dict.product.itv">
          </subscription-itv-panel>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row" v-if="subscription_dict.product.voip">
        <div class="col-xs-6">
          <panel icon="icon-voip">
            <translate slot="title">Phone</translate>
            telefon products
          </panel>
        </div>
      </div>
    </panel>

    <div v-else class="text-center">
      <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-pulse fa-3x fa-fw"></i>
    </div>

    <span v-if="subscription_dict"><b>subscription_dict.product.voip : </b>{{ subscription_dict.product.voip }}</br></span>
    <span v-if="subscription_dict"><b>subscription_dict.product : </b>{{ subscription_dict.product }}</br></span>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import PageTitle from '../../core/components/PageTitle.vue'
  import SubscriptionHsiPanel from './SubscriptionHsiPanel.vue'
  import SubscriptionItvPanel from './SubscriptionItvPanel.vue'
  import Panel from '../../core/components/Panel.vue'
  import Icon from '../../core/components/Icon.vue'
  import api from '../../core/api.js'

  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        subscription_dict: false,
        error: false
      }
    },
    props: ['requests_url', 'context'],
    computed: {
      _subscription_address() {
        var sub_address = this.subscription_dict.subscription_address
        return sub_address + ' - ' + this.subscription_dict.package.join(' - ')
      }
    },
    created() {
      this.get_subscription()
      this.translate()
    },
    methods: {
      get_subscription() {
        let self = this
        api.get_subscription(self.requests_url.subscriptions_request)
        .then(function(response) {
          self.subscription_dict = response
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
          if(error) {
            self.error = error
          } else {
            self.error = self.$gettext(
              'We were not able to retrieve your subscription information!')
          }
        })
      },
      translate() {
        this.$gettext('Bridge hsi')
        this.$gettext('Bridge voip_biz')
        this.$gettext('Router')
      }
    },
    components: {
      PageTitle,
      Panel,
      Icon,
      SubscriptionHsiPanel,
      SubscriptionItvPanel
    }
  }
</script>

<style lang="sass">
  @import "../../core/css/tooltip"

  .table
    table-layout: fixed

    > tbody > tr >
      th
        width: 33%
      td
        vertical-align: middle
</style>
```

And here is my test `subscription.js`:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import translations from 'src/translations.json'
import GetTextPlugin from 'vue-gettext'
import VTooltip from 'v-tooltip'

import Subscription from 'src/subscription/components/Subscription'

jest.mock('../../core/api');

Vue.use(GetTextPlugin, {
  availableLanguages: {
    en: 'English',
    fr: 'Français',
    de: 'Deutsch',
  },
  defaultLanguage: 'fr',
  translations: translations
})
Vue.use(VTooltip)

it('render when error', (done) => {
  const renderer = require('vue-server-renderer').createRenderer()
  const vm = new Vue({
    el: document.createElement('div'),
    render: h => h(Subscription, {
      props: {
        requests_url: {
          subscriptions_request: 'error_empty_promise'
        }
      }
    })
  })
  renderer.renderToString(vm, (err, str) => {
    setImmediate(() => {
      expect(str).toMatchSnapshot()
      done()
    })
  })
})
```

The component's method `get_subscription()` use my API function `get_subscription`:

```
import axios from 'axios'

export default {
  get_subscription(url) {
    return axios.get(url, {
      credentials: 'same-origin'
      })
      .then(function(response){
        if(response.data.error){
          return Promise.reject(response.data.error)
        }else{
          return Promise.resolve(response.data)
        }
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        return Promise.reject(false)
      })
  }
}
```

For my test, I have mocked this function like this :

```
const promises_object = {
  error_empty_promise: new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    process.nextTick(
      () => reject(false)
    )
  })
}

export default {
  get_subscription(url) {
    return promises_object[url]
  }
}
```

Now, in the test I render and compare against a snapshot. My issue is, I can't find a way to wait that the promise of `get_subscription` is `reject` before making the comparison. 
The result is that my snapshot reflect the state of the component before the update of the DOM, which is done after the asynchronous call on the API.
Is there a way to tell jest to wait until the `Promise` is `reject` before calling `expect(str).toMatchSnapshot()` ?

Comment: https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/tutorial-async.html

Comment: Thank you, I know this example. Can you show me how you apply that in my case ? In the example he calls the asynchronous function directly in his test and so can resolve the `Promise` object. Here I can't do that because the function is called when the component state is `created`.

Comment: Create a new Promise and return it. Set it up to do its test and resolve in the `reject` clause of the other Promise.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't get it. I already return a `Promise` from my mocked API. Where do I need to "Create a new Promise and return it." ? Thank you for your help so far!

Answer (score 0):

[Jest docs](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/tutorial-async.html) say

> `it` expects the return value to be a Promise that is going to be
>   resolved.

You have a promise that is going to be rejected, so you need a Promise that resolves when your promise is rejected.

```
  isRejected(rejectingPromise, someExpects) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      rejectingPromise.then(
        () => null,  // if it resolves, fail
        (err) => {   // if it rejects, resolve
          // Maybe do someExpects() here
          resolve();
        }
    });
  }
```

Comment: I've tried with your solution, but the snapshot is still made before the `get_subscription` `Promise` is rejected. I still have the snapshot made with the spinner instead of the error message.

Comment: Maybe put the snapshot call inside a [nextTick](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-nextTick) call?

Comment: That doesn't work. The nextTick call only wait until the next DOM update. Here we have to wait until the Promise is resolved/rejected. That's where I am stuck.

Comment: If you put the snapshot test where I put the "Maybe do some expect here", it shouldn't happen before reject/resolve.

Comment: I don't get it, the code of `get_subscription(url)` that you paste above is in `src/core/__mocks__/api.js`. It's the mocked API. And the tests of the component using this mocked API are in `src/__tests__/subscription/subscription.js`. So when the `it()` statement is in `subscription.js`, how can the related `expect()` statement be in `api.js` ? I must have missed something in your solution.

Comment: Your test code doesn't call `get_subscription`, so I don't know how you're testing it. You need, somewhere, to have the code that translates a rejected promise into a resolved promise. The resolved promise is what should be returned by the test code. I've updated my response to make it an `isRejected` test.

Comment: My Vuejs component `Subscription.vue` call the local `get_subscription` method in the `created` callback. The local `get_subscription` method is defined in the `methods` of the `Subscription.vue`. (you can see the code in my question, in the first code container). So in my test, when I instantiate the `Subscription.vue` component, the `get_subscription` method is called once the component reach the `created` state.